# Why can't my Arduino compare above 10?

Tags: c++, variables, arduino, comparison, sensors

I'm on an Arduino project where I constantly measure the the air pressure and calculate a relative height from the first measurement using the Adafruit_BMP085 library.

I display the current value and a peak value. It basically works, but as soon as the current height exceeds 10m it stops updating the peak value.

Sketch looks something like this:

```
#include <Adafruit_BMP085.h>

String currentAltitude;
String peakAltitude;
int32_t groundpressure;

Adafruit_BMP085 bmp;

void setup() {
    groundpressure = bmp.readPressure();
}

void loop() {
    currentAltitude = bmp.readAltitude(groundpressure);
    if (currentAltitude > peakAltitude) { 
        peakAltitude = currentAltitude;
    }
    Serial.println("Current: " + currentAltitude + "m");
    Serial.println("Peak: " + peakAltitude + "m");
    delay(10);
}
```

What I get (when I raise the sensor/ or increase air pressure) is something like this:

```
Current: 0m
Peak: 0m

Current: 4m
Peak: 4m

Current: 11m
Peak: 4m (still)
```

Why does it stop comparing. Is it due to the type of variable I'm comparing?

Comment: You do understand the difference between text and a number, right?

Comment: You are doing a string compare, and "1" is less than "4".

Comment: `bmp.readAltitude(groundpressure)` returns a float not a String.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is due to the fact that you are using the overloaded `>` operator to a `String` type which is probably performing a lexographic, not a numerical, comparison.

Convert your string data to numbers before performing arithmetic operations.

Answer (score 2):

Strings compare different than numbers. For example the string `"10001"` in lexicographical order is "smaller" than `"2"` (ie in a dictionary `"10001`" would come before `"2"`).

You either need to implement proper comparison of number-strings or (most likely much easier) convert the strings to numbers before you compare them.

Answer (score 0):

Try to convert bmp.readAltitude(groundpressure) to int with some int = stoi(bmp.readAltitude(groundpressure , nullptr, 10) and compare resulted int.

Comment: `bmp.readAltitude(sealevelPressure)` already returns a `float`.

Comment: Then currentAltitude must be float.